# Is the following metric space complete?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $X=\{x=(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \ \vert \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N} :  x_i \geq 0  \ \ \forall i \geq N\}$ and let $\bar{\rho}$ be the uniform metric on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. Is $(X, \bar{\rho})$ complete?

My effort: The uniform metric is $\bar{\rho} \colon \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\times \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as follows:
$$ \tilde{\rho}( x, y) \colon= \sup \left\{ \ \min \left\{ \ \vert x_\alpha - y_\alpha \vert, \ 1 \ \right\} \ \colon \ \alpha \in \mathbb{N}\ \right\} \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \colon= \left(x_\alpha \right)_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}}, \ y \colon= \left(y_\alpha \right)_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}.$$
I have tried to prove that it is complete. Let $(x_n) \subseteq X$ be a Cauchy Sequence, and let $\varepsilon>0$, then $\exists K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n,m \geq K$ then $\bar{\rho}(x_n,x_m)< \varepsilon$. Since $x_n \in X$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $x_n=(x_i^{(n)})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ then $\exists N_n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_i^{(n)} \geq 0$ for all $i \geq N_n$ and by the definition of supreme we have that
$$\min\{ \vert x_i^{(n)}- x_i^{(m)} \vert, 1 \}< \varepsilon, \quad \forall i \in \mathbb{N}.$$
And this is what I have at the moment. Am I on the right way or do you think this space is not complete?

Comment: Consider the sequence $(x^n)_n$, where $x^n_i=-1/i$, for all $i\le n$, while $x^n_i=0$, otherwise.

Comment: @Ruy I have proved that the sequence is Cauchy. But I can't prove that it doesn't converge on $X$. I've tried to do it by contradiction, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you prove that it converges to a point in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}\setminus X$?

Comment: @Ruy No, I've had problems with that.

Comment: The limit is the sequence $(-1/n)_n$.

Comment: You might want to prove that convergence in your metric implies convergence of all coordinates. This allows you to get the limiting sequence that Ruy mentioned.